# How can I use Python to extract information from a HTML document?

Tags: python, html

I need python to extract some data from a HTML file.

The code I am using at the moment is bellow:

```
import urllib
recent = urllib.urlopen(http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ps4/call-of-duty-ghosts/team/TeamCrYpToNGamingEU/match?id=46057240)
recentsource = recent.read()
```

I now need this to then print a list of the gamer tags that are in the table of that webpage for the other team.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: use beautifulsoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module, which is a wonderful text parser.

If you do not want to or can't install it, you can download the source code, and just put the .py file in the same directory as your program.

To do so, download and extract the code from the website, and copy the "bs4" directory into the same folder as your python script.

Then, put this in the beginning of your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# or
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
# To type bs instead of BeautifulSoup every single time you use it
```

You can learn how to use it from other stackoverflow questions or look at the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) for this job or you can use [ntlk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk).

A sample code

```
import nltk   
from urllib import urlopen
url = "http://any-url"    
html = urlopen(url).read()   
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)

print(raw)
```

Answer (score 0):

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) has some helpful constructs for pulling data from HTML pages, and the results tend to be self-structuring and self-naming (if you set up the parser/scanner correctly). Here is a pyparsing solution for this particular web page:

```
from pyparsing import *

# for stripping HTML tags
anyTag,anyClose = makeHTMLTags(Word(alphas,alphanums+":_"))
commonHTMLEntity.setParseAction(replaceHTMLEntity)
stripHTML = lambda tokens: (commonHTMLEntity | Suppress(anyTag | anyClose) ).transformString(''.join(tokens))             

# make pyparsing expressions for HTML opening and closing tags
# (suppress all from results, as there is no interesting content in the tags or their attributes)
h3,h3End = map(Suppress,makeHTMLTags("h3"))
table,tableEnd = map(Suppress,makeHTMLTags("table"))
tr,trEnd = map(Suppress,makeHTMLTags("tr"))
th,thEnd = map(Suppress,makeHTMLTags("th"))
td,tdEnd = map(Suppress,makeHTMLTags("td"))

# nothing interesting in column headings - parse them, but suppress the results
colHeading = Suppress(th + SkipTo(thEnd) + thEnd)

# simple routine for defining data cells, with optional results name
colData = lambda name='' : td + SkipTo(tdEnd)(name) + tdEnd

playerListing = Group(tr + colData() + colData() + 
                        colData("username") + 
                        colData().setParseAction(stripHTML)("role") + 
                        colData("networkID") + 
                        trEnd)

teamListing = (h3 + ungroup(SkipTo("Match Players" + h3End, failOn=h3))("name") + "Match Players" + h3End +
                table + tr + colHeading*5 + trEnd +
                Group(OneOrMore(playerListing))("players"))



for team in teamListing.searchString(recentsource):
    # use this to print out names and structures of results
    #print team.dump()
    print "Team:", team.name
    for player in team.players:
        print "- %s: %s (%s)" % (player.role, player.username, player.networkID)
        # or like this
        # print "- %(role)s: %(username)s (%(networkID)s)" % player
    print
```

Prints:

```
Team: Team CrYpToN Gaming EU
- Leader: CrYpToN_Crossy (CrYpToN_Crossy)
- Captain: Juddanorty (CrYpToN_Judd)
- Member: BLaZe_Elfy (CrYpToN_Elfy)

Team: eXCeL™
- Leader: Caaahil (Caaahil)
- Member: eSportsmanship (eSportsmanship)
- Member: KillBoy-NL (iClown-x)
```